# Trying to allow only these combos through regular expression

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am trying to allow only these combo's through regex and using a RegularExpressionValidator, these are the combination that my company uses as a employee number(I know weird).

- 9999999
- 999999
- 99999
- 9999999-9
- 999999-9
- 99999

This needs to at max 9 characters liked showed within the longest example,
I have tried a few expression with no luck can anyone spot what is wrong with it?

```
^(\d+(-\d{1,3}))
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your second group optional by adding `?` to it.

```
^(\d+(-\d{1,3})?)
```

Your original regex wanted `-{some digits}` to be there. But by adding `?` you make it optional.

Edit:

For maximum 9 digits, you can just use:

```
if("string".Length <= 9){
    // now do regex calculations here
}
```

Comment: you never said that in your question @MBiggs

Comment: Apologies I thought I had made that clear by outlining with the examples, I can add that in the question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

**Eight digits at the most, with other characters thrown in: you need a lookahead**

We need to tweak your regex in various ways. First, let me give you the final regex.

```
^(?=(?:\D*\d){1,8}$)\d{1,8}(?:-\d{1,3})?$
```

1. First, we need to anchor the regex with `^` and `$` so that we don't validate something valid, followed by more stuff that invalidates the regex, such as `123 and my dog`
2. Second, the `(?=(?:\D*\d){1,8}$)` is a lookahead that checks that at this point in the string (the very beginning), we are able to match any non-digit followed by a single digit, one to eight times, followed by the end of the string. This is to limit the number of total digits to 8.
3. Instead of `\d+` for the first bit, let's use `\d{1,8}` so we don't waste our time matching 5000 digits then failing.
4. The `(?:-\d{1,3})?` is an optional non-capturing group that matches a dash followed by 1 to 3 digits. The `?` is what makes it optional.

Please let me know if you have questions. :)